# How can I create and install two different versions of a WPF ClickOnce application?

Tags: wpf, configuration, installation, clickonce

I have a WPF application distributed with ClickOnce. The current setup is that we have two different versions based on two different Configurations in two different deployment sites (they connect to different databases). They work fine independently of each other, but they can't both be installed on a computer at the same time. Is there any way to fix this so that the two versions don't conflict with each other when you try to install them both?

If it helps, I already have pre-build events set up swap in a different config file that is to be used based on the current Configuration.

Comment: Do they have different URL?

Comment: Yes. They each have their own deployment website.

Answer (score 0):

Continuing on from [Sergey's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3556088/sergey-vaulin) comment based on [a related vlog](https://robindotnet.wordpress.com/2009/04/22/clickonce-installing-multiple-versions-concurrently/) I have documented a solution:

## Steps

- Create a source control (github) branch for the 'Test' version, with 'Live' on master (any branching arrangement should work as long as there are two)

  - `git branch Test`
  - `git push -u origin Test` (this could be done once the local changes below are made)
- In Visual Studio 2017 (VS) under 'Publish... Application' add "Test" postfix to the 'Assembly name'
- In VS under 'Publish... Publish' add "Test" postfix to the 'Publishing Folder Location' and the 'Installation Folder URL'
- In VS under 'Publish... Publish... Options...' add "Test" postfix to the 'Product name'

### Custom Steps

- Add "Test" postfix to log file name (we use log4net configured in 'App.config')
  `<file value="${LOCALAPPDATA}\\Our_Company\\log-Test.txt" />`
- Any other files or resources used by the application (we don't have any)
- We have an application icon in 'Resources' that has a different colour for the 'Test' version than the 'Live'

After these steps go ahead and 'Publish' and there are two desktop versions. Then we share the links, to the setup.exe, by email with our users.

Finally, once the test (QA) phase is complete merge the 'Test' branch to 'master' (or whichever branch 'Live' is on) and reverse the renaming steps above (i.e. remove all the "Test" postfixes). And reverse any custom steps too.

Comment: It's hard to say but if there's a Publish function then I suspect so. Otherwise I would try the same steps but use MageUI. It's very similar to the Publish feature but I haven't used it in anger myself.

Answer (score -1):

They must have different application names. I don't know how to change application name before publishing, but you can try to change it by this utility [Download page](http://www.devowl.net/2017/04/Alternative-Mage-UI-Sozdanie-ClickOnce-prilozheniya.html) (first one link). Your actions:

1. Choose you second instance application folder.
2. Change action to Update
3. Add any char in you string "Application instance name" [preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IC5Vd.jpg)
4. Click build